# How do I perform an Enum binding to a view's model in .NET's MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enums, type-conversion, model-binding

How can I bind an enum into a drop down in MVC to make the model be valid after a post?
Not sure does it need a converter or something else, I provide the code, what is your recommended solution?
*(the below code causes ModelError)*

**Enum :**

```
public enum TimePlan
{   Routine = 0,
    Single = 1 }
```

**The Model :**

```
 public TimePlan TheTimePlan { get; set; }

 public SelectListItem[] TimeList { get; set; }
```

**Controller :**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Education(EducationViewModel EducationModelInfo)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        { ...
    } }
```

**The View Binding :**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CourseTimePlan, Model.TimeList, "Please select the time plan")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't shown how you populated this TimeList collection. Try like this and it should work:

```
public TimePlan TheTimePlan { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TimeList
{
    get
    {
        var enumType = typeof(TimePlan);
        var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<TimePlan>();

        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(enumType);

        return
            from value in values
            select new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = converter.ConvertToString(value),
                Value = value.ToString(),
            };
    }
}
```

or to make it a little more generic you could write a reusable helper:

```
public static IHtmlString DropDownListForEnum<TModel, TEnum>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression
)
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
    var enumType = GetNonNullableModelType(metadata);
    var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<TEnum>();
    var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(enumType);

    var items =
        from value in values
        select new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = converter.ConvertToString(value), 
            Value = value.ToString(), 
            Selected = value.Equals(metadata.Model)
        };

    return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, items);
}
```

and then your model could only contain the Enum value:

```
public TimePlan TheTimePlan { get; set; }
```

and in your view use the helper:

```
@Html.DropDownListForEnum(x => x.TheTimePlan)
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I add a "please select ..." on these? the way I used to do not work here.

Comment: Sure, just add it as parameter to the helper.

Comment: I tried something like this as a test : return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, items,"Please select from the list below"); but the selected index of the dropdownlist is always "1" not "0".

Comment: That's normal, enums are value types. If you want to be able to have such default value you should declare it as a nullable enum on your view model.

Comment: @Darin Can you share `GetNonNullableModelType` method