# Nullable Enum helper for having a default value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nullable, html.dropdownlistfor

I recently made an extension for binding a dropdownlist to a model,
Unfortunately I couldn't make the -wanna be default- **"please select..."** be selected as default
Always the dropdown's index is 1 and it selects the Enum's 1st item as the default item.
I made the extension based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18248755/50506) -Darin's great answer-

I get advised to use **nullable enum**,
I couldn't make it work yet, hope get a help on it

The specification of the default selection text in the helper:

```
return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, items, "Please select ...");
```

How to make the "please select..." selected as default in any dropdowns.

In the ViewModel I used:

```
public TimePlan? TimeList { get; set; }
```

Comment: I know removed the second piece to don't cause a misconception of the question

Comment: what is getting rendered in html? have you checked that?

Comment: Can't get exactly what you mean, the enum is fully rendered and I have the select hint at the top, the problem is it's not selected and the index 1 will be the selected item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. It's not the TimeList that should be nullable, but the TimePlan property that is supposed to store the selected item. Here is what you should have in your View Model:

```
public TimePlan? TheTimePlan { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TimeList
{
    get
    {
        var enumType = typeof(TimePlan);
        var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<TimePlan>();

        return
            from value in values
            select new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(TimePlan), value),
                Value = value.ToString(),
            };
    }
}
```

Then, in your View, you'll have:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TheTimePlan, Model.TimeList, "Please select...")
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to create a custom html helper you can do it like this:

```
public static IHtmlString DropDownListForEnum<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression, string optionLabel)
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
    var enumType = GetNonNullableModelType(metadata);
    var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<TEnum>();            

    var items =
        from value in values
        select new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = Enum.GetName(enumType, value),
            Value = value.ToString(),
            Selected = value.Equals(metadata.Model)
        };

    return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, items, optionLabel);
}

private static Type GetNonNullableModelType(ModelMetadata modelMetadata)
{
    Type modelType = modelMetadata.ModelType;

    Type underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(modelType);
    if (underlyingType != null)
    {
        modelType = underlyingType;
    }
    return modelType;
}
```

Then, in your View, you'll have:

```
@Html.DropDownListForEnum(model => model.TheTimePlan, "Please select...")
```

Comment: I'm using something like "@Html.DropDownListForEnum(x => x.TheTimePlan)", also as I commented there I tried this which won't work as expected : "I tried something like this as a test : return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, items,"Please select from the list below"); but the selected index of the dropdownlist is always "1" not "0".", I'm playing with the code to find the workaround and let you know, thanks

Comment: couldn't find any difference between your code and the previous post

Comment: There are only two small differences. 1- TimePlan is nullable in my code (`TimePlan?`). 2- The DropDownListFor html helper has an optionLabel argument ("Please select..."). And, it works. I've tested it. This is based on the first solution in the answer provided for the other question. You don't have to create a custom html helper for something like this.

Comment: Check my updated answer, if you want to use a custom html helper.

Comment: I was away from here, but friend you know I'm not looking for just a big answer, the exact answer as I saw and tried before, All the things you mentioned were exactly in the link I mentioned, I think you didn't test it yourself cause the result is the same and doesn't show the OptionLabel on the page load (it's hidden beneath the combobox.

Comment: I have tested it. It works. You are doing something wrong. Can you update the question with your complete code? The code in your question is obviously wrong (`public TimePlan? TimeList { get; set; }`). Or, at least describe what happens. Do you get an error message? Where?

Comment: There is no errors, I don't have any extra item in my code, what do you mean is wrong with "public TimePlan? TimeList { get; set; }" ?! you have here the same. So when your page loads you have the OptionsLabel as the default selected value?

Comment: I don't have the same. Please pay more attention. That's why I'm asking you to post your complete code.

Comment: And, yes, I do have optionLabel as the default selected value, when the page is loaded.

Comment: And, by the way, my code here is different from the one in the other link. I'm using a different way to get the Text for the SelectListItems. And, I'm using a nullable enum.

Comment: The new pieces of your code were mentioned in the comments section of the link I provided, I pasted them here were exactly the same as my code and the result was the same, but I found the problem, because you mentioned you see them the right form I checked the enum and I found I set their values starting from 0, changed the starting point to 1 and the problem resolved, may be  without the values also they be right, please edit your post and remove the whole code, and mention the lines related to the optionLabel within 2-3 lines, I think the answer look better that way, Thank you for your time.

Comment: When you use a nullable enum, it doesn't matter if you start your enum values from 0 or 1. It works anyway.